# What does 二周目 mean?

Tags: translation

I find this all over the net, but can't find it defined anywhere.

I'm trying to understand this tweet:

じゃあ二周目は是非モノマネで♪( ´▽｀)RT @mimiroll_410: @mao_sid 今友達とカラオケに入ってるシドの曲を五十音順に全部制覇しようとしてます！(笑)ちなみに今は土曜日の女です＼(^O^)／

What does the first sentence say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

目 is used as an *ordinal* suffix. <s>It's the difference between "2 weeks" and (like in this case) "the 2**nd** week".</s>

**Edit:** Sorry for failing so blatantly. :( Updated answer, now with less obvious errors!:

So in this case, Mao is suggesting that "the second *round* " be Sid impersonations (the first "round" is singing all the Sid songs in the Karaoke machine in alphabetical order).

Comment: Wrong しゅう; you're thinking 週.

Comment: With the full word being 「第二周目」, same as other ordinals, e.g. 「第一番目」 -> "first"/"foremost".

Comment: @Ignacio - can you site an example??  I've never heard of those being used interchangeably.

Comment: "Doing all Sid songs in (Japanese) alphabetical-order" (The Japanese 50-sound-order; not 50 songs).

Answer (score 2):

Needs more context.  ～周 means "(a) round" or a "cycle" or a "revolution".  So if you're talking about a race (horse, car, etc.) it would be the 2nd lap.  Since a "cycle" of a business, establishment, etc. is usually a year (the length of one revolution around the sun), it can also mean 2nd year the place has been open for operation.  Or just at iteration number of some regular event; the 2nd times it's happened.

---

**EDIT**: I'd say the first sentence says, "OK, round 2 will be impersonations (of people)."